# How to leave out the Space before I use auto-completion by Tab in TexShop?

Tags: mac, editors, texshop, auto-completion

These days I am trying to improve my typing speed on TexShop by employing the Command Completion source.
However, I've found that I have to type in a Space before using, say, "xg+Tab" to represent \gamma, even when the character right before it is not a letter but something like "+","/" or other special characters (so in such cases I think that the editor should not be stupid enough to misunderstand what I'm trying to do).

Thus I want to know how to activate auto-completion without typing in a Space all the time.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The auto-completion doesn't know anything about the source properties (i.e., it doesn't distinguish characters) and therefore must use spaces as a way to delimit the completion strings. I don't think there's any way around this short of making a feature request to the TeXShop team. If you make your completions begin with \ then you can avoid the space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment @AlanMunn! It's very nice of you.

Comment: Since I think that's the only answer, I'll convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-completion doesn't know anything about the source properties (i.e., it doesn't distinguish characters) and therefore must use spaces as a way to delimit the completion strings. I don't think there's any way around this short of making a feature request to the TeXShop team. If you make your completions begin with \ then you can avoid the space.

So if instead of using `xg` as your auto-complete string for `\gamma` you use `\xg`, things will work well without needing the space.